# WSO2 external IdP registration: manage several AttributeConsumingService

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server version 5.8.0 and 5.9.0
I'm facing this problem: I have external IdPs and I want to allow SAML integration with these IdPs. I can register them in WSO2 and all works pretty good.

The isssue is related to the `AttributeConsumingService` In the external IdP I registered this WSO2 ServiceMetadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="_3574ad74-ba7a-4ea5-b3e8-dbb2dafb55df" entityID="http://wso2_590_ai">
   <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
      <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
         <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
               <ds:X509Certificate><!--Certificate info--></ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
         </ds:KeyInfo>
      </md:KeyDescriptor>
      <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" />
      <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
      <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localhost:9443/commonauth" index="0" isDefault="true" />
      <md:AttributeConsumingService index="0">
         <md:ServiceName xml:lang="it">set0</md:ServiceName>
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field A" Name="fielda" />
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field B" Name="fieldb" />
      </md:AttributeConsumingService>
      <md:AttributeConsumingService index="1">
         <md:ServiceName xml:lang="it">set1</md:ServiceName>
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field A" Name="fielda" />
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field B" Name="fieldb" />
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field C" Name="fieldc" />
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field D" Name="fieldd" />
      </md:AttributeConsumingService>
      <md:AttributeConsumingService index="2">
         <md:ServiceName xml:lang="it">set2</md:ServiceName>
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field A" Name="fielda" />
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field C" Name="fieldc" />
      </md:AttributeConsumingService>
      <md:AttributeConsumingService index="3">
         <md:ServiceName xml:lang="it">set3</md:ServiceName>
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field A" Name="fielda" />
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field D" Name="fieldd" />
      </md:AttributeConsumingService>
      <md:AttributeConsumingService index="4">
         <md:ServiceName xml:lang="it">set4</md:ServiceName>
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field B" Name="fieldb" />
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field D" Name="fieldd" />
      </md:AttributeConsumingService>
      <md:AttributeConsumingService index="5">
         <md:ServiceName xml:lang="it">set5</md:ServiceName>
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field B" Name="fieldb" />
         <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Field C" Name="fieldc" />
      </md:AttributeConsumingService>
   </md:SPSSODescriptor>
   <md:Organization>
      <md:OrganizationName xml:lang="it">Service provider WSO2 590</md:OrganizationName>
      <md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="it">WSO2 590</md:OrganizationDisplayName>
      <md:OrganizationURL xml:lang="it">https://localhost:9443/</md:OrganizationURL>
   </md:Organization>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

As you can see in my metadata I can handle several `AttributeConsumingService`. How can I tell WSO2 that a ServiceProvider wants to use the `AttributeConsumingService number 1`, another the `AttributeConsumingService number 2` and so on?

The only point where I can set AttributeConsumingService is during the external IdP registration but it is little bit weierd because I should register several time the same IdP with related entityId issues....

Thank you

Angelo

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able in solving this.

I modified the `org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.manager.DefaultSAML2SSOManager.buildAuthnRequest(HttpServletRequest, boolean, String, AuthenticationContext)` method. Just after the instruction

```
//Get the inbound SAMLRequest
AuthnRequest inboundAuthnRequest = getAuthnRequest(context);
```

I added the following piece of code:

```
Integer attrConsServiceIndex = inboundAuthnRequest.getAttributeConsumingServiceIndex();
if( attrConsServiceIndex != null && attrConsServiceIndex > 0 ) {
   if( log.isInfoEnabled() ) {
log.info("Inbound SAML Request AttributeConsumingServiceIndex "+ attrConsServiceIndex+" Settato nella auth request SAML");
    }
authRequest.setAttributeConsumingServiceIndex(attrConsServiceIndex);
}
```

In this way if the Application handled by a Service Provider sends an AttributeConsumingServiceIndex different from 0, this is set in the AuthnRequest that WSO2 IS builds for the external IdP.
I don't know if there is a different way to solve it but as far as I investigated this is the only solution I found

I hope this is useful

Angelo